# Firefox - input type number hides decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I got some inputs on a webform. I'm calculating things here. When I calculate stuff (using JS) I use .toFixed(2) function every time.
In IE and Chrome Numbers are always shown with 2 decimal places. That's what I want. **In Firefox decimal places are getting hide.**

Here some example of my control: `<input type="number" value="19.00" name="tax" id="tax" min="0" step="0.01" class="input_number" tabindex="3">`

**Output:**
    - IE: 19.00
    - FF: 19
    - Chrome: 19.00

**Solution:**

Solution found and tested with the help the possible duplicate and the marked answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/duuy884a/7/

```
<input type="text" min="0" step="0.01" name="test" id="test" value="" pattern="[0-9]+([,\.][0-9]+)?" />
<input type="text" min="0" step="0.01" name="test2" id="test2" value="" readonly />
<button onclick="set()">check</button> 

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function set (  ){
    if ( document.getElementById("test").value.length <= 0 ){ return; }

    document.getElementById("test").value = document.getElementById("test").value.replace(/,/g, '.');
    var fInput = parseFloat( document.getElementById("test").value );
    if ( isNumber( fInput ) == true ){
        document.getElementById("test2").value = checkZeros( document.getElementById("test") );
    }
}

function checkZeros ( oInput ){
    if ( oInput.value === '') {
        return;
    }

    oInput.value = parseFloat(  oInput.value ).toFixed(2);    
    oInput.value =  oInput.value.toString();

    if ( oInput.value.indexOf('.') === -1) {
         oInput.value =  oInput.value + '.00';
    }
    while ( oInput.value.indexOf('.') >  oInput.value.length - 3) {
         oInput.value =  oInput.value + '0';
    }

    return oInput.value;
}
```

Comment: I found this Q too, but I didn't thought it will help me. Sry for not reading exactly. I think this could help me but this would mean I need to ad an event-listener for each input? I got around 15 of them and the user can add more to the form ...

Comment: Since you are using this field for output/display purposes only and the user can not directly manipulate the value (at least in your fiddle) – why use a `number` field at all here? Simple `text` field, and the problem is gone – no? (Whether this even justifies the use of a form element _at all_ might be another question.)

Comment: In real I got a form for creating a bill. Which means the user can input data in my input-fields and calculate sum's and other stuff. This is why I use number field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution based on the fiddle given by the OP in the comments section of the answer.**

Change the `test2` input type to `text`. And it'll work the way you want it to.

```html
<input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" value="" readonly />
```

Comment: I do this, but the Outpot shown in my Question is still the same.

Comment: can you show your script please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/duuy884a/ do this using Firefox, and maybe using another browser.

Comment: I've posted an edit. Check it out

Comment: Yes but this means the user can input letters too .. I try to avoid this because it's a form for creating bills.

Comment: No you have to make the second box as text where are showing the output!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86886/discussion-between-psylogic-and-mike).

Comment: I want this trailing 0's on all my controls, even on the one where the user entered data.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox sees your value as a string and not as a number, try setting value as 19(Without quotation marks) then using toFixed(2) should set the value to 19.00 for calculating stuff.