# Formatting a decimal variable to decimal places loses formatting in firefox

Tags: formatting, salesforce, decimal, currency, apex

I have a decimal variable value I set scale two decimal places that is displayed into an input field. The visualforce page uses dynamic updating of this field and it works great. The problem is when I use firefox all decimal fomatting is removed, its like it turns to an int. (the inclusivePriceDisplay populates the incl input field). I cannot use the currency formatting field because of a calculation I am not saving to the record as one of my fields, inclusivePrice is not included on any object so does not have the salesforce currency formatting.
how it looks ext class:

```
decimal inclusivePriceDisplay= inclusivePrice.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

How it looks VFP:

```
    <apex:input required="true" value="{!inclusivePriceDisplay}" type="number" label="{!$Label.InclPrice}">
</apex:input>
```

How it looks on Chrome:
[image]

How it looks firefox:

[image]

Its like if its a whole number it refuses to put the trailing zeros and the decimal.  I even initialize the variables to 0.00 and it only shows to 0. However if the decimal should be more than 2 decimals it will show 2 decimals but if it is like $1.10 (a dollar and ten cents) it will only show 1.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984894/firefox-input-type-number-hides-decimal-places

Comment: @Musselman unfortunately I cannot use such attributes like step to help with this, salesforce/visualforce does not allow it.